# Pass 3 parameter to powershell function can not show separate parameter

Tags: powershell, syntax

I want to pass 3 parameter from c# to powershell function but the output it show all parameter in same line. How to fix it ?

This is powershell code

```
param (
    [string] $param1,
    [string] $param2,
    [string] $param3
)
# begin
function AddStuff($x, $y ,$z) 
{ 
   "x: $x;" 
   "y: $y;"
   "z: $z;"
}

AddStuff $param1, $param2, $param3
# end
```

This is c# code.

```
    RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
    runspace.Open();
    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    string scriptfile = @"C:\Users\test2.ps1";
    Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile);
    CommandParameter testParam1 = new CommandParameter("param1", "paramvalue1");
    CommandParameter testParam2 = new CommandParameter("param2", "paramvalue2");
    CommandParameter testParam3 = new CommandParameter("param3", "paramvalue3");
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam1);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam2);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam3);
    pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }
    MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

when I run it show MessageBox like this.

```
   x: paramvalue1 paramvalue2 paramvalue3; 
   y: 
   z:
```

That is wrong. Why it not show like this.

```
   x: paramvalue1 ; 
   y: paramvalue2 ;
   z: paramvalue3 ;
```

Comment: **In PowerShell, functions are invoked _like shell commands_** - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo(arg1, arg2)`; see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).  
If you accidentally use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a function sees as a _single_ argument.  
To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PowerShell script, do not use commas to separate arguments when you call AddStuff:

```
AddStuff $param1 $param2 $param3
```

When you do

```
AddStuff $param1, $param2, $param3
```

you are actually creating a PowerShell [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6) that contains $param1, $param2, and $param3; this array is then passed to the first parameter ($x) of AddStuff, which is why you got the unexpected output.

If you test your PowerShell script first in e.g., [PowerShell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6), you can spot these sort of problems much more easily, before worrying about how to call the script from C#.